# Get Row Index on Asp.net Rowcommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I have an asp.net GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Faktor" ShowHeader="False" Visible="True">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn1" CssClass="SelectRow" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
            CommandArgument='<%#(eval("mprID")) %>' CommandName="ViewFactors" ImageUrl="~/tadarokat/Images/factor.png"
            Text="" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How Can I get `rowIndex` on row command event?

I want to highlight (`select`) target row when `RowCommand` fires.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

this is answer for your question.

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
```

Answer (score 15):

ImageButton \ Button etc.

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'
```

code-behind

```
protected void gvProductsList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.CommandArgument;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Or, you can use a `control` class instead of their types:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

int RowIndex = row.RowIndex;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a built-in command of GridView like insert, update or delete, on row command you can use the following code to get the index:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

In a custom command, you can set the command argument to `yourRow.RowIndex.ToString()` and then get it back in the RowCommand event handler. Unless, of course, you need the command argument for another purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use @rahularyansharma's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6503483/5377037) above in my own project, with one minor modification. I needed to get the value of particular cells on the row on which the user clicks a `LinkButton`. The second line can be modified to get the value of as many cells as you wish.

Here is my solution:

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
string typecore = gvr.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gvProductsList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int RemoveAt = gvr.RowIndex;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Products"];
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(RemoveAt);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            ViewState["Products"] = dt;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
protected void gvProductsList_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        gvProductsList.DataSource = ViewState["Products"];
        gvProductsList.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```