# How to get index of the gridview row

Tags: asp.net

How can i get row index of the grid view whose child control is doing post back. *I know the way of getting control causing post back and finding its parent container which returns grid view row and then find its index.*  I want this in a RowDataBound event to check selectedrow index and formatting the same. Is there any other property or settings which directly emits selected index of the grid view on any child control post back

Edit:

For example if there is a dropdownlist in a row and there are certain rows in a gridview. Then i want gridview rowindex where postback happens due to that dropdowlist in the gridview row.

Comment: And what do you want to do on that point where you get the value? Do you want to delete that row from gridview?

Comment: on the basis of that index i want to format(design) the row and also change the data sources for the downstairs in that row.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the index of the row in `RowDataBound` via the [`RowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex.aspx) property:

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
    }
}
```

You can get the index of any child control in a GridView via

- `childControl.NamingContainer` =>
- `GridViewRow` =>
- `RowIndex`

for example in a `DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) sender;
    GridViewRow row  = (GridViewRow)  ddl.NamingContainer;
    int index        = row.RowIndex;
}
```

**Finally**: since you've mentioned *" to check selectedrow index"*, if you're actually looking for the selected row index of the `GridView` itself, there's a property just for this:

- [`GridView.SelectedIndex` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx)

Comment: I want index of the row which causing postback

Comment: here is a to find row index on row command link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503339/get-row-index-on-asp-net-rowcommand-event

Comment: Yes i saw this, thanx for the responses but i want something more. I have gone through this. But i do not want to invoke any method. Just want to simpliest way to get selectedindex of the gridview

Comment: on the basis of that index i want to format(design) the row and also change the data sources for the downstairs in that row.

Comment: yes i can get the solution by your way but it requires calling separate function, from this getting naming container and then find row index, i want same index without calling this or i need to know is there any way which directly gives me the selectedindex

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19574/discussion-between-eraj-and-tim-schmelter)

Comment: @dran: i have deleted my comments to clean this question from unnecessary "noises". Maybe you wantel to delete yours also.