# How to get value of particular cell at row command field of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using following expression.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

I want to get the row index, but the value of index is coming like `0x000000` something.

Comment: Please give a more complete code sample showing where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int index = 0;
int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument as string, out index);
```

Not sure from your question in which context you're trying to obtain the index, but in the RowDataBound event handler, you would get the index as described here:

[How to get index of the gridview row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394695/how-to-get-index-of-the-gridview-row)

Comment: i use this statement. but it again give that type value.

Comment: when i run my project then i click on button field of 2nd row of grid view, them command agrument get the value 1 bt the index gives value 0x00000001. i am using this in RowCommand event of grid view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288168/how-to-get-row-index-according-to-clicked-button-from-asp-net-gridview