# Trouble grabbing Row Number from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow

I have the following GridView:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SysInvoiceID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SysInvoiceID" HeaderText="SysInvoiceID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SysInvoiceID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BillMonth" HeaderText="BillMonth" SortExpression="BillMonth" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="InvoiceDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InvoiceDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNumber" HeaderText="InvoiceNumber" SortExpression="InvoiceNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Net" HeaderText="Net" SortExpression="Net" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VAT" HeaderText="VAT" SortExpression="VAT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gross" HeaderText="Gross" SortExpression="Gross" />
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ViewInvoice"  HeaderText=" " ShowHeader="True" Text="View" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind the page:

```
public partial class PagingTest01 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if (e.CommandName == "ViewInvoice")
    {
        // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
        // property to an Integer.
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
        // by the user from the Rows collection.
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        // Now you have access to the gridviewrow.

        ViewButton_Click(row);
    }
}




protected void ViewButton_Click(GridViewRow row)
{ 
    byte[] FileImage = GetImageData(0,row);

      if (FileImage != null)
      {
          base.Response.Clear();
          base.Response.Buffer = true;
          base.Response.ContentType = "Application/x-pdf";
          base.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
          string attachment = string.Format("attachment;filename=\"Invoice_{0}.pdf\"", "Customer1");
          base.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
          base.Response.BinaryWrite(FileImage);
          base.Response.Flush();
          base.Response.Close();
          base.Response.End();
      }
}





public byte[] GetImageData(int sysInvoiceID,  GridViewRow row)
    {

        string strUserID = CommonCode.GetCurrentUserID().ToString();
        string strCustomerID = CommonCode.GetCurrentCustomerID().ToString();
        byte[] numArray;

        string strConnectionString = "Data Source=TESTSERV;Initial Catalog=DB_Invoices;Persist Security Info=True";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select FileImage from DB_Invoices.dbo.Bills WHERE (FileType = 'PDF' AND SysInvoiceID = @ID)", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            connection.Open();



            da.Fill(ds);
            DataRow item = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            byte[] item1 = (byte[])item["FileImage"];
            ds.Tables.Clear();
            numArray = item1;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return numArray;
    }



}
```

So basically I have a GridView with a lot of rows, each one with a 'View' Buttonfield next to it. When 'View' is clicked, I attempted to make use of GridView1_RowCommand which should hopefully grab the row clicked before passing it onto ViewButton_Click. This will then call GetImageData and pass the row number onto this line:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text);
```

Cell 0 is the SysInvoiceID column, so if the correct row is passed, @ID will be assigned a SysInvoiceID.

'Row' however doesn't seem to be a valid argument, though I can't think why not... Unless I have to explicitly convert it into a int? Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Side-note: if `ID` is an `int` you should use `int.Parse(celltext)`, othwerwise the database gets the wrong type since `AddWithValue` needs to infer the type from the value.

Comment: Just noticed something... Before the code would at least work if I explicitly typed a row number such as 1, however nothing is happening at the moment. From the looks of things I don't think ViewButton_Click is being called properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just commented this as *side-note* but maybe it's your issue because you mention that *"it doesn't seem to be a valid argument, though I can't think why not... Unless I have to explicitly convert it into a int"*.

If `ID` is an `int` you should use `int.Parse(celltext)`, othwerwise the database gets the wrong type since [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) needs to infer the type from the value.

So use:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Text));
```

Apart from that, you haven't added the event handler `GridView1_RowCommand`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SysInvoiceID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   ....
```

and you are also not setting the `CommandArgument` to the index of the row. I would use a different approach anyway if you need the row-index. Use a templatefield and a control, for example a `Button`. Then use it's `NamingContainer` property to get the reference to the 'GridViewRow`, here is an example: [Get Row Index on Asp.net Rowcommand event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503339/get-row-index-on-asp-net-rowcommand-event)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not know about that! Though yes, this didn't fix the particular issue I am having.

Comment: @JimmyK: Edited my answer, you haven't added the event handler `GridView1_RowCommand` and some other things.

Comment: Managed to get this working with everyones help! I'll mark this as the answer since you gave me the most support, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
int index = ((GridViewRow)((WebControl)sender)).RowIndex;
```

in place of

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```