# Get column value from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm new to ASP.NET and I am using GridView to display data on a web page. I also added a button in Gridview called process orders.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" autogenerateselectbutton="True"     GridLines="None" AllowPaging ="true" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        >

        <Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Process" runat="server" 
      CommandName="processorders" 
CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
      Text="Process orders" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I used the row command method to get the selected index of the row.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.CommandName == "processorders")
        {
    // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
    // CommandArgument property.
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
```

Also I've implemented selectedIndexChanged method for the default select button:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        txtbox.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[3].Text + ".";
    }
```

If I try to use the GridViewRow in GridView1_RowCommand I get a null pointer exception. The row is always null but it works fine in GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged. 
What am I trying to achieve is, get the column value from the selected row using my Process button and then use that value to update a database. I don't want to do it using Select.
And is there any way I can use row.Cells[] without specifying the index. I want to get the value of a column name.
Help? Please ??

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503339/get-row-index-on-asp-net-rowcommand-event