# Onclick Event on a dynamically created ButtonField in GridView c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, event-handling

I have dynamically created a column within a gridview for a button to appear in each row. And am trying to get an onclick event to work.

```
 ButtonField test = new ButtonField();     
 test.Text = "Details";
 test.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
 test.CommandName = "test";
 GridView1.Columns.Add(test);
```

My asp basic as everything is dynamically added to the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server"> </asp:GridView>
```

This appends the button(s) fine however I can't seem to find a parameter to add an on-click event on  the test button field.

I've tried:

```
   void viewDetails_Command(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (test.CommandName == "test")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),     "alertMessage", "alert('Event works')", true);
        }
    }
```

This doesn't run as I assume it's not bound to anything however I cant see where  I would bind this event function to? Just using an alert message to test the onclick works!

Any help would be great!

Comment: When are you creating that button?

Comment: The ButtonField is being initiated at the top of the scope, the buttons are added to the columns on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the [RowCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event.

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Beside:

```
public partial class DynamicGridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var test = new ButtonField();
            test.Text = "Details";
            test.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
            test.CommandName = "test";
            GridView1.Columns.Add(test);


            GridView1.DataSource = new[] {
                new {Id= 1, Text = "Text 1"  },
                new {Id= 2, Text = "Text 2"  },
            };
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "test")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Event works')", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from yours @dan6657?

Comment: It was just the OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" and e.Command name I think - Thanks!

Comment: Awesome @dan6657, I'll highlight that in the answer

Comment: Another quick one If I may, if this button is being set in every row in the column with some data in a different column but same row, would I be able to access the same row data with same row button, if you get the what I mean? I was thinking about foreach/for loops however they'd just iterate over the set and print it out based on whatever value x is at in the loop. Edit: I could do something like a rowID and then if button x is in rowID x give me the data in that row?

Comment: @dan6657 check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503339/get-row-index-on-asp-net-rowcommand-event